# Возможность создания изолированных docker сетей с одинаковым пулом адресов

Tags: docker

Возможно ошибаюсь в терминологии.
Что имеется ввиду:

1. на одном хосте создаем сети 2 сети `net_a` и `net_b`:

> docker network create -d "драйвер" --subnet 172.21.0.0/24 net_a
> docker network create -d "драйвер" --subnet 172.21.0.0/24 net_b

2. добавляем 2 контейнера `а1`, `а2` к сети `net_a` и 2 контейнера `b1`, `b2` к сети `net_b`:

> docker run -d --privileged --rm --net net_a --ip 172.21.0.2 .... a1
> docker run -d --privileged --rm --net net_a --ip 172.21.0.3 .... a2
> docker run -d --privileged --rm --net net_b --ip 172.21.0.2 .... b1
> docker run -d --privileged --rm --net net_b --ip 172.21.0.3 .... b2

3. соответственно не должно быть конфликта. Контейнеры `a1`, `a2` видят друга и не видят `b1`, `b2` и наоборот.

Как можно реализовать данную конфигурацию?

Comment: а зачем именно иметь одну и ту же подсеть? создайте две сети и поместите в них контейнеры, это должно решать вашу задачу, да ip будут разные, но это проблема?

Comment: Задача стоит именно такая.
В моем случае есть десятки(дорастет до сотен) конфигурационников  со статическими адресами интерфейсов(по несколько интерфейсов на контейнер).
Чтобы все это вручную не задавать и не следить за правильностью ввода:
задаем рандомные сети  с заранее известным пулом адресов и заранее ожидаемыми  ip, а после  выполнения задачи удаляем сеть.

Comment: Данную конфигурацию вы не сможете   реализовать ни как. Начиная с того что вы не сможете создать две разных сети  с пересекающимися адресами. 

На этом можете остановиться и подумать как сделать правильно.